# History of Kronecker's Divisorentheorie

Tags: kronecker

I saw André Weil's Weil divisor. So I became curious about the history of the divisor. However, when I searched the history of divisor, I found that Leopold Kronecker announced the beginning of the concept of divisor with his Divisorentheorie. So I would like to know the background and history of how Kronecker came up with the concept of Divisorentheorie.

Comment: Edwards gives a detailed account in [The Genesis of Ideal Theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133600), sections 10-12, and he compares and contrasts Kronecker's theory of divisors to Dedekind's theory of ideals.